# Set sublime text to read .asp files as .php files (with php syntax)

Tags: macos, php, sublimetext

I have a few `.asp` files that I want to edit with Sublime Text, however, I always have to change the syntax to `PHP` under View -> Syntax -> PHP. Is there anyway that I can make Sublime Text automatically read it as PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to View → Syntax → Open all with current extension as... and select PHP. Check the image below:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I actually looked at that option without really paying attention. thanks.